# Job for httpd.service failed

Tags: linux, http, server, centos, systemd

I am getting this error and sites are not opening now

> Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

I got this problem after doing this

```
yum remove php php-cli php-common php-gd php-ldap php-mysql php-odbc php-pdo php-pear php-pecl-apc php-pecl-memcache php-pgsql php-soap php-xml php-xmlrpc
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Please post your Question at https://askubuntu.com/ and provide the output of `systemctl status httpd.service` as well as `journalctl -xe | grep -i "httpd"`

Comment: So, did you run `journalctl -xe`? What did it say?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is a configuration file left for php in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` that is loaded by default by apache (having the .conf extension). Since you have removed php, php module can't be loaded and httpd throws that error being unable to start.

So go to /etc/httpd/conf.d, see what .conf files you have there and either remove the php.conf file or at least comment the php module in it so it won't be loaded when apache is restarted. Then try again to restart apache by issuing `systemctl restart httpd`